# Catching NDSolve Singularities

Tags: numerical-integration, error-tracking

I am using NDSolve to solve a system of equations with changing initial conditions (I'm using NDSolve multiple times). However, for particular initial conditions I am getting an effective step size of 0 during the integration. Is there a way to detect this in NDSolve and output some useful info?

i.e.:

```
x10 = 1.2
x20 = 3.2
eqn1 = x1''[t] ==  (x1[t] - x2[t]) / (x1[t] - x2[t])^2
eqn2 = x2''[t] ==  (x1[t] - x2[t]) / (x1[t] - x2[t])^2

NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, x1[0]==x10, x2[0]==x20, x1'[0]==0, x2'[0]==0}, {x1[t], x2[t]}, {t,0,1}]
```

I have tried adding the following to NDSolve:

```
WhenEvent[(x1[t]-x2[t])==0, "StopIntegration"; Print[x10,x20]]
```

But the WhenEvent command doesn't stop the integration before it sees the singularity, and thus I don't see the Print command. I need to see the Print command because I have code that loops over the first block above and tries random values of x10 and x20. I need to know what initial conditions make the integration fail.

Comment: Have you tried something like `Check[NDSolve[..], {x10,x20}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monitor the step size.  It will be "effectively zero" well before it is zero.  The code below does not quite do what you want, I think, because it cannot trap `NDSolve` after it has decided to exit. When `NDSolve` fails due to step size "zero," it does not take the last step.  At best you can only catch the next-to-last step, and probably you have to aim a little earlier than that.  But maybe it's helpful.

The `threshold` to use is one of the weak points.  It depends on the `Method`.  The `"Extrapolation"` method seems really hard to trap, because it can fail even when the next-to-last step is large.

```
SeedRandom[4];
xcurrent =.;
threshold = 75 + 1; (* relative size to x * $MachineEpsilon *) 
y0 = 1.;
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2, y[0] == y0, 
   WhenEvent[
    x - threshold*$MachineEpsilon*Abs[x] - xcurrent < 0 // TrueQ,
    {Print["Whoa, there!: ", {x, y0, y[x], NDSolve`Self}];
     y[x] -> (y0 = RandomReal[])}]},
  y, {x, 0, 10}, StepMonitor :> (xcurrent = x)]
```

> `` Whoa, there!: {1.,1.,2.15996*10^12,NDSolve`StateData[<0.>]} ``
>
> `` Whoa, there!: {4.21155,0.311376,3.971*10^11,NDSolve`StateData[<0.,1.>]} ``
>
> `` Whoa, there!: {5.97832,0.566004,3.73592*10^11,NDSolve`StateData[<0.,4.21155>]} ``
>
> `` Whoa, there!: {7.57282,0.627155,2.85592*10^11,NDSolve`StateData[<0.,5.97832>]} ``

Also beware the step size criterion is no good when `x` is close to zero. One should replace it with an absolute step size appropriate to the problem at hand.